# Surface offline maps

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, maps

I'm developing Surface application, but I came across a problem. I need to develop a control with next abilities:

1. World map on background (should display only continents).
2. I need a way to find out on which continent user touched(interactive background map).
3. Any controls can be added on the top of the map control (for an example video-player control for different regions of the map).
4. Map control should works in offline mode only (without any
   connection to internet).

I can't find any frameworks that would meet my goals.
So, anyone know something projects/code samples that can help me to achieve my goals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offline mapping could be done in many ways, one of them would be download / get [shapefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) for continents. *(You can search for that)*. Later you can use [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) to display that shapefile in WPF application. SharpMap is a .Net framework based open source application which enables reading multiple geospatial formats. 
Another option to read geo-spatial data is [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/).